# Form design - can't make form bigger than screen resolution during design

Tags: visual-studio, winforms, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a laptop with a small resolution like 1366x768. I want to design a `Winform` form for users working with bigger resolution. But I can't make the form bigger in the design.
Moreover, the form size was decreased when I switch laptop resolution to smaller.

I read about a similar problem: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/00e5efce-bf4f-4e80-95e6-4e08b1ad9ac6/cant-resize-form?forum=winforms
They say that is not possible to design bigger forms than screen resolution.
Is it really true?

Thank you in advance for your answers.
Jaro

BTW.
I don't need to resize form during runtime like http://blogs.artinsoft.net/Mrojas/archive/2011/08/11/Making-a-form-bigger-than-the-Screen-Resolution.aspx

```
This is just the transliteration of that code in C# just as a reference

using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class Form1 : Form
{
    [DllImport("User32.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Ansi, SetLastError = true, ExactSpelling = true)]
    private static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr hWnd, int x, int y, int w, int h, bool Repaint);

    private void Form1_Load(System.Object sender, System.EventArgs e)
    {
        this.MaximumSize = new Size(5000, 800);
        bool Result = MoveWindow(this.Handle, this.Left, this.Top, 5000, 500, true);
    }
    public Form1()
    {
        Load += Form1_Load;
    }

}
```

Comment: Usually you should design sizable forms for smallest acceptable size by setting suitable anchor and dock for controls and using table layout panel or flow layout panel. What is the requirement which pushes you to design for larger resolution?

Comment: The usual resolution in the office is 1600x900 and bigger. But I need to work in smaller resolution because of my eyes. If there is no other solution I'll need to solve this by going up with my laptop resolution or switch to an external monitor. But for now, I'm looking for possibilities.

Comment: You can never know what will be the size of a user's display. Make you application DPIAware, resizable (as Reza Aghaei described) and give means to save the disposition (size and location), so next run the window will be presented sized as the user wants it to be.

Comment: Thank you for your remarks. You are right. I'll go that way.

Comment: None of the comments answer the actual question - IS there a way to design a From larger than the display on which you are conducting your design work?